# How to submit dynamically created hidden variables using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a dynamic table. [**DEMO to my project**](https://jsfiddle.net/rush2ashu/hmfpkdxh/).

I have placed this dynamic table in the form under a div named 'box'

```
<div id="box">
</div>.
```

I am creating dynamic hidden variables table using Jquery which I need to store in DB. This is how I am creating the hash to submit to server.

```
criteria = $('form_name').serialize(true);
criteria = Object.toJSON(criteria);
// Build the object to store the parameters for the AJAX post request
parameters = {
  title : $('report_title').value,
  description : $('report_description').value,
  criteria : criteria
}

// Make the AJAX post request
new Ajax.Request( URL, {
  method: 'post',
  parameters: parameters,
  onSuccess: function( response ) {
    $('messageSpan').innerHTML = response.responseText;
    $('spinner').style.display='none';             
  }
 });
```

I am not able to capture the dynamically created values in the criteria.
How to solve this?

In the dynamically created section, I tried adding a submit button and see if the values can be fetched. I am able to fetch and iterate all the hidden variables.

```
$('#jquerysaveButton').click(function(){
    jsonObj = [];
    $("input[id=rubric_cell]").each(function () {
        var id = "cell_" + row + "_" + col;
        item = {}
        item["id"] = id;
        item["selected_rubric"] = $(this).val();
        jsonObj.push(item);
    }); 
    console.log(jsonObj); //I am getting the required values here
});
```

How to get these values in the `criteria = $('form_name').serialize(true);`. Am I doing some thing wrong? Please help me. thanks in advance. 
[**DEMO to my project**](https://jsfiddle.net/rush2ashu/hmfpkdxh/)

Comment: yes. you are almost right... but i cant see form in your code...

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your hidden input fields have a name attribute set otherwise $.serialize will not process them.